# Re: FullCalendar (by Adam Shaw) mobile version bug on iPhone devices

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, facebook, fullcalendar

I am developping a web app based on FullCalendar by Adam Shaw, but I am actually using an older version supporting the mobile version ([link](https://github.com/JordanReiter/fullcalendar-mobile)) , I am actually quite done developping the web app and tested it on android machines and PC's and it worked quite perfectly, though iPhone devices are unable to parse specific calendar events

the web app has an engine that fetches event data from Facebook and Google Calendar and Firebase servers, I am able to fetch the events from all three providers and display on FullCalendar mobile on iPhone only the latter two (Google Calendar and Firebase server), though on Facebook event data, it just won't display the events on the FullCalendar.

I managed to print the events, show them on alerts (the one that won't display), so I am certain the Facebook Graph API is not the issue ( which is what I was hoping), it seems that the issue is with the FullCalendar itself, however I can't find a reason for FullCalenar API to treat the same event data differently, if it was parsing issue, the events wouldn't display on Android and PC machines, so I am quite certain it's not something wrong with the code per se, but more of some requirement only needed for iPhone machines

Help is much apperciated

```js
var page_module = (function ()
{
 let facebook_app_id = "1888264188125920";
 let pw = "Mgo6B97nHZKdwXMiGw5P";
 let events = []; // where ALL the events will be
 let users = []; // where all the users info will be
 let google = [];
 let fb = 0; //
 let uneffective_load = 0;
 const initModule = function()
 {
  get_users_db();
  //// Calendar initation virtual space ////
  let elemDiv = document.createElement('div'); // limits the calendar UI into a div named calendar1
  elemDiv.id = "calendar1"
  elemDiv.className = "calendar1";
  const speculated_height = window.innerHeight * 0.70; // 70% height
  document.body.appendChild(elemDiv);
  $('#calendar1').fullCalendar(
  {
  height:  speculated_height,
  header: { // defines the header of the calendar (buttons)
    left: 'prev,next,today',
    center: 'title', // which month/year we are in
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    theme: true,
    eventRender: function(event, element) // generates pop up info about the event
    {
   element.attr('title', event.tooltip);
    },
    isRTL: false, // Right to left, hebrew mode
     monthNames: ["ינואר", "פבואר", "מרץ" , "אפריל", "מאי", "יוני" , "יולי" , "אוגוסט", "ספטמבר" , "אוקטובר", "נובמבר", "דצמבר"], // hebrew language use (month names)
    monthNamesShort: ["ינואר", "פבואר", "מרץ" , "אפריל", "מאי", "יוני" , "יולי" , "אוגוסט", "ספטמבר" , "אוקטובר", "נובמבר", "דצמבר"], // fullcalendar api for short month names, in hebrew it's short anyways
    dayNames: ["ראשון", "שני", "שלישי" , "רביעי" , "חמישי", "שישי", "שבת"], // hebrew day names
  dayNamesShort: ["ראשון", "שני", "שלישי" , "רביעי" , "חמישי", "שישי", "שבת"], // ...
  buttonText: // buttons in hebrew
  {
   prev:     'הקודם', // <
   next:     'הבא;', // >
   prevYear: 'שנה קודמת',  // <<
   nextYear: 'שנה הבאה',  // >>
   today:    'היום',
   month:    'חודשי',
   week:     'שבועי',
   day:      'יומי'
  },
  columnFormat: 
  {
    month: 'ddd',    // Mon
    week: 'ddd d/M', // Mon 7/9
    day: 'dddd d/M'  // Monday 7/9
  },
  timeFormat:
  {
    agenda: 'h:mm{ - h:mm}', // 5:00 - 6:30
    
    // our case
     '': 'h:mm{ - h:mm}'            // 5:00 - 6:30
  },
   eventClick: function(event) // on click event handler, uses event object
   {
     if (event.url)
     {
    window.open(event.url);
    return false;
     }
   },
   
  
  });

   //// END OF Calendar initation virtual space ////
  

   /// Facebook API initation virtual space ///
   // depends on IP being either localhost or specific firebase-project approved by author
  FB.init(
  {
    appId      : ''+facebook_app_id,
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.8'
  }); // API call function to "throw" API ID and be approved upon IP filtering of Facebook management
  /// END of Facebook API initation virtual space ///

  //Table build metafunction
  build_filter_table();
  
 };


 const gather_all_events_from_all_facebook_pages = function()
 {
  // subdibision into local function!

  const add_event_to_calendar = function(id, name, date, email, enddate,location, source,url) // subfunction responisble for adding event to fullcalendar API event and render that
  {
   let color = "#";
   users.forEach(function(val)
   {
    if(val.id == email)
     color+=val.color;
    return;
   });
   let event;
   if(source == "Facebook")
    event = {id: email , title: name , start: date, end:enddate , url: 'https://www.facebook.com/events/'+id , backgroundColor: color, event_source: email, tooltip: name, location,allDay:false,};
   else if(source == "Manual")
    event = {id: email , title: name , start: date, end:enddate , url: url , backgroundColor: color, event_source: email, tooltip: name, location, allDay:false,};
   else if(source == "Google")
    event = {id: email , title: name , start: date, end:enddate , backgroundColor: color, event_source: email, tooltip: name, location,allDay:false,};
   events.push(event);
  };

  const withdraw_events_from_facebook_page = function(data, email) // subfunction responsible for scanning entire event database file from facebook page
  {
    // subfunction to print results into Fullcalendar API
   let i;
   for(i=0; i<data.length; i++)
   {
    let event_date = new Date(data[i].start_time); // sets a new Date for event date formating to be dynamic
    //event_date.setISO8601(data[i].start_time); // converts time from Facebook API date format to Javascript Date format
    let end_date;
    if(data[i].end_time)
     end_date= new Date(data[i].end_time);
    let place_name;
    if(data[i].place)
     place_name = data[i].place.name;
    else
     place_name = null;
    add_event_to_calendar(data[i].id, data[i].name, event_date, email, end_date, place_name ,"Facebook");
   }
  };

  const page_through_all_events_from_response = function(response,email)
  {
   withdraw_events_from_facebook_page(response.data,email); // adds all the event from THIS page to the event array
    if(response.paging.next) // if there's a next page
    {
    $.getJSON(response.paging.next, function(next_data) // recursive call to gather the events from the next page (until done)
    {
     page_through_all_events_from_response(next_data,email);
    });
   }
  };

  const add_events_from_page = function(str, email) // subfunction responsible for doing the API request for the event database
  {
   //+"&since="
   let month_ago = parseInt(new Date(moment().subtract(2, 'months')).valueOf()/1000);
   let month_ahead = parseInt(new Date(moment().add(2, 'months')).valueOf()/1000);
   FB.api
   (
    "/"+ str+"/events?access_token="+config_module.getaccessToken(pw)+"&since="+month_ago+"&until="+month_ahead, // the HTTP request defined in FB API
    function (response)
    {
      if (response && !response.error) // if request was approved by server
      {
      page_through_all_events_from_response(response, email);
      }
      else
      {
       console.log(response.error);
      }
    }
   );

  };
  const scan_for_direct_events = function() // manual event entry - database scanner
  {
   let database = firebase.database();
   let leadsRef = database.ref('Events'); // gets to database /Events folder
   leadsRef.once('value',function(snapshot)
   {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot)
    {
     if(childSnapshot.val().approve == 1) // add each child that is "approved" by admin to the event database
     {
      add_event_to_calendar(childSnapshot.val().id, childSnapshot.val().name, new Date(childSnapshot.val().start_time),
       childSnapshot.val().id, new Date(childSnapshot.val().end_time),childSnapshot.val().location, "Manual",childSnapshot.val().url);
     }
    });

   });
  };
  const scan_all_db_for_pages = function() // subfunction responsible for facebook DB load via Firebase API call
  {
   let database = firebase.database();
   let leadsRef = database.ref('Facebook'); // go to /Facebook folder on database
   leadsRef.once('value',function(snapshot)
   {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot)
    {
     if(childSnapshot.val().charAt(0) == '1') // adds each child that is approved by admin (child being a facebook page)
      add_events_from_page(childSnapshot.key,childSnapshot.val().substring(1, childSnapshot.val().length));
    });

   }).then(scan_google_calenders);
  };
  
  scan_for_direct_events(); // add manual events
  scan_all_db_for_pages(); // adds all events from facebook database
  $(document).ajaxStop(function ()
  {
   local_storage_func(); // "filters" the rendering of the events on the page from the last picked configuration
     // 0 === $.active
  });
 };
 const create_buttons = function() // creates the navigation buttons
 {

  let div = document.createElement("div"); // div for navigation buttons
  div.id = "top_buttons_div";
  div.className = "top_buttons_div";
  const back_button_build = function()
  {
   let link = document.createElement("a");
   let pic = document.createElement("IMG");
   pic.src = "buttons/admin.png";
   pic.height = 45;
   pic.width = 75;
   link.appendChild(pic);
   link.href = "login_page/login.html";
   div.appendChild(link);
  };
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  back_button_build(); // defined it into functions for future possibility for modularity
 };
 const get_users_db = function() // scans the entire user database to create users array
 {
  let database = firebase.database();
  let leadsRef = database.ref('Users'); // get to Users folder on firebase db
  leadsRef.once('value',function(snapshot)
  {
   snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot)  // build user array while each user object consists of user id and user color
   {
    let email = childSnapshot.key;
    let obj = childSnapshot.val();
    let user_obj = new Object(); // create the user "object"
    user_obj.id = email;
    user_obj.key = childSnapshot.key;
    user_obj.color = obj.color;
    user_obj.url = obj.url;
    users.push(user_obj); // adds to array
   });

  }).then(function()
  {
   database.ref("Names").once('value',function(snapshot2) // appends user nickname to user id at users array
   {
    snapshot2.forEach(function(childSnapshot)
    {
     users.forEach(function(val,index,arr)
     {
      if(val.id == childSnapshot.key)
       val.name = childSnapshot.val(); // actual appending call
     });
    });
   }).then(render_table_content) // appends user data to GUI table
  }) // scan_google_calenders

 };
 const scan_google_calenders = function()
 {
   const add_event_to_calendar = function(id, name, date, email, enddate, source,url) // subfunction responisble for adding event to fullcalendar API event and render that
   {
    let color = "#";
    users.forEach(function(val)
    {
     if(val.id == email)
      color+=val.color;
     return;
    });
    
    let event;
    if(enddate == "Full day")
    {
     event = {id: email , title: name , start: date , backgroundColor: color, event_source: email, tooltip: name,url: url, allDay:true};
    }
    else
    {
     event = {id: email , title: name , start: date, end:enddate , backgroundColor: color, event_source: email, tooltip: name,url: url};
    }
    events.push(event);
   };

   let database = firebase.database();
   let leadsRef = database.ref('Google'); // go to /Facebook folder on database
   leadsRef.once('value',function(snapshot)
   {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot)
    {
     let obj = childSnapshot.val();
     users.forEach(function(val)
     {
      if(obj.id == val.id)
      {
       obj.color = val.color;
       obj.name = val.name;
       google.push(obj);
      }
     });
    });

   }).then(function()
   {
    google.forEach(function(val)
    {
      
      var calendarid = val.val; // will look somewhat like 3ruy234vodf6hf4sdf5sd84f@group.calendar.google.com

      $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' + calendarid+ '/events?key=' + config_module.google_key,
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (response) 
       {
        response.items.forEach(function(event)
        {
   
         let s = new Date(event.start.dateTime);
         if(s.toString() == 'Invalid Date' && event.summary)
         {
          add_event_to_calendar(val.id, event.summary, new Date(event.start.date), val.id, "Full day" ,null, event.htmlLink);
         }
         else
         {
          let e = new Date(event.end.dateTime);
          if(event.summary)
           add_event_to_calendar(val.id, event.summary, s, val.id, e ,null, event.htmlLink);
         }
        });
        
        //do whatever you want with each
       },
       error: function (response) 
       {
        //console.log(response);
        //tell that an error has occurred
       }
      }); 
    });
    
    
   });
 };
 const build_filter_table = function()
 {
  let table = document.createElement("table"); // builds a new table
  table.id = "table";
  let main_row = table.insertRow(0); // creates the first line which on each cell we define the cell's content on different lines
  let main_cell1 = main_row.insertCell(0);
  let pic1 = document.createElement("IMG");
  pic1.src = "icons/Organization.png";
  main_cell1.append(pic1);
  let main_cell2 = main_row.insertCell(1);
  let you_get_nothing_good_day_sir = document.createElement("IMG");
  you_get_nothing_good_day_sir.src = "icons/Color.png";
  main_cell2.append(you_get_nothing_good_day_sir);
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = "div_table";
  div.className = "div_table";
  div.appendChild(table);
  document.body.appendChild(div);
 };
 const render_table_content = function()
 {
  const checkbox_handler = function(e) // function is responisble for alerting between "filter" and "unfilter" state according to checkbox value
  {
   let status = "";
   let element = e.srcElement || e.target;
   if(uneffective_load == 0)
   {
    element.checked = false;
    alert("Page is not ready yet");
   }
   if(element.checked == true)
   {
    status="addEventSource"; // "command" to do
    localStorage.setItem(element.id,"1");
   }
   else
   {
    status = "removeEvents"; // "command" to do
    localStorage.setItem(element.id,"0");
   }
   add_remove_by_id(element.id,status);
  };
  let i=1;
  let table = document.getElementById("table");  // adds data to table
  users.forEach(function(val,index,arr)
  {
   let row = table.insertRow(i);
   let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
   let user_nick = "";
   if(val.name == null) // will be either username or nickname (if exists), nickname having the apperhand
    user_nick+= val.id;
   else
    user_nick+= val.name;
   if(val.url && val.url.length > 0)
    cell1.innerHTML = "<a href='" +val.url+ "'>" + user_nick + "</a>";
   else
    cell1.innerHTML = user_nick;
   let cell2 = row.insertCell(1); // "color" sample cell
   cell2.style.backgroundColor = "#" + val.color; // color defination
   let cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
   let checkbox = document.createElement("INPUT"); // dummy function box with the aforementioned event handler to switch between states
   checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
   checkbox.checked=false;
   checkbox.id = val.id;
   checkbox.addEventListener('click', checkbox_handler);
   cell3.appendChild(checkbox);
   i++;
   if(index+1 == arr.length) // will actually render the events (not just from facebook pages, but from everything) after completing the table with all the data
   {
    gather_all_events_from_all_facebook_pages();
   }
  });
  

 };
 const add_remove_by_id = function(email,status) // status being the command to do, email is the id
 {
   let temp_arr = new Array();
   let month_ago = new Date(moment().subtract(2, 'months'));
   let month_ahead = new Date(moment().add(2, 'months'));
   events.forEach(function(val,index,arr) // creates a temproary array that holds all the events that are linked to the user with id==email
   {
    if(val.id == email && val.start.valueOf() > month_ago.valueOf() && val.start.valueOf() < month_ahead.valueOf() )
    {
     temp_arr.push(val);
    }
   });
   if(status == "addEventSource") // if the command was to add those events
   {
    $('#calendar1').fullCalendar(status,temp_arr); // we add those events from the array
   }
   else
   {
    $('#calendar1').fullCalendar(status,email); // full calendar API special function that handles "remove event" rendering
    //$('#calendar1').fullCalendar('removeEvents',id);
   }
 };
 const local_storage_func = function() // reads the local storage for previous table filtering "configuration" to apply them
 {
  uneffective_load = 1;
  $.each(localStorage, function(i) // reads ALL the local storage values
  {
   if(document.getElementById(localStorage.key(i)) != null && localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)) == 1) // if value is 1, we grab the key as source id
   {
    document.getElementById(localStorage.key(i)).click(); // and applies "click" emulation
   }
  })
  $('#calendar1').fullCalendar("rerenderEvents");
  
 };
 return { initModule, gather_all_events_from_all_facebook_pages, create_buttons, events,users,build_filter_table,local_storage_func,google};

}());



$( document ).ready(function()
{
 let logo = document.createElement("IMG");
 logo.src = "icons/lit1.jpg";
 logo.id = "logo";
 logo.style.width = "100%";
 document.body.append(logo);
 //document.header.append(h);
 page_module.initModule(); // second move, make EVERYTHING, snowball function
 page_module.create_buttons(); // first move -> creates the navigation buttons
 document.getElementsByClassName("fc-border-separate")[0].tBodies[0].style.opacity = "0.5";
 //document.getElementsByClassName("fc-view fc-month-view fc-basic-view")[0].firstChild.tBodies[0].style.opacity = 0.5
});
```

```css
div.top_buttons_div
{
 width: 100%;
}

div.calendar1
{
 width:100%;
}

div.div_table
{
 width: 100%;
}

body
{
 background-image: url('icons/background.jpg');
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!--Full Calendar API and jquery API loading files-->
    
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='libs/fullcalendar-1.5.2/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
  <script src='libs/fullcalendar-1.5.2/jquery/jquery-1.7.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js'></script>
  <script src='libs/fullcalendar-1.5.2/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
  <!--END of Full Calendar API and jquery API loading files-->
  
  <!--Facebook API script files-->
  <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/es_LA/sdk.js"></script>
  <!--END of Facebook API script files-->

  <!--Google Firebase API loading files-->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.7.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.7.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.7.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
  <!--  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>  -->
  <!--END of Google Firebase API loading files-->
  
  <!--Loaded a personal script to combine API's as well as page design and logic initate-->
  
  <script src="config.js"></script> <!--Required in order to access Firebase & Facebook databases while identifying ourselves-->
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <!--END of Loaded a personal script to combine API's as well as page design and logic initate-->
  
  <!--Loaded theme script files and css files-->
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='libs/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.css' />
  <script src='libs/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.js' />
  <!--END of Loaded theme script files and css files-->
  
  <script src='libs/polyfill/modernizr-custom.js'></script>
  <script src='libs/polyfill/js-webshim/minified/polyfiller.js'></script>
  <script>
   $.webshims.polyfill();
   
  </script>
    
 </head>
 
 <body> 
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this. I just ran into this. None of the events in my calender display at all on iphones, but do on anything else.